# How can I select a part of TM_DIRECTORY variable?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I want to select a part of the TM_DIRECTORY variable on VScode snippet. I mean I want to select `Tests\Setup` of the `d:\Projects\Hakhsin\hakhsin\tests\Setup` in code-snippet file. Look at this:

```
// On snippet file
"PHP Class": {
        "scope": "",
        "prefix": ["phpClass"],
        "body": [
            "<?php\n\nnamespace ${TM_DIRECTORY/(?<=(?:[\w:\\]hakhsin\\)).+(?=\\)//};\n\nclass ${TM_FILENAME_BASE} {\n\t$2\n}"
        ],
        "description": "New PHP Class"
    },
```

And I want to get this result:

```
namespace Tests\Setup;

class StorageFactory {

}
```

But I get this result:

```
<?php

namespace d:\Projects\Hakhsin\hakhsin\tests\Setup;

class StorageFactory {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear you can use variables inside of other variables in a snippet transform.

You can try this code which is more "dynamic" than yours but not perfect:

```
"${TM_DIRECTORY/([^\\\\]*\\\\){4}(.*)/${2:/capitalize}/}",
```

The `{4}` in that is if you have 4 segments in the directory structure before the part you want, like `d:\Projects\Hakhsin\hakhsin\tests\Setup` The segments are `d:\`, `Projects\`, `Hakhsin\` and `hakhsin\`.  If that number of segments is known and stable than the snippet I showed works well.

I doubt the number of those segments would vary within a project but might very well between projects - you would just have to change the `{x}` item for each project if so.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it but it is not dynamic.

```
namespace ${TM_DIRECTORY/(.*hakhsin\\\\)(.*)/${2:/capitalize}/};
```

Is there a better way? anything like this:

```
namespace ${TM_DIRECTORY/(.*${WORKSPACE_NAME}\\\\)(.*)/${2:/capitalize}/};
```

This is the result:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Setup;

class StorageFactory {

}
```